# How We can open PDF in flutter after choose app from tray

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app to open PDF files. I have added an intent filter to show my application as PDF Opner.

[image]

Now, How can we get the PDF path so that I can open PDF in the flutter application?

Thanks In advance.